# Who holds the Modern Era record for most hits in a nine inning Major League Baseball game?

Tags: baseball, history, mlb

Only one man in Major League Baseball history has recorded seven hits in seven at-bats during a regulation nine-inning game.

- Who was this player?
- For what team did he play?
- Who was the losing team?
- Why was this game particularly embarrassing for the losing team?
- What were the stats for that game?
- What kind of hits did he have in his seven at bats?
- Who pinch-hit for this player and why?
- What are the most important events in this player’s Major League
  Baseball career?
- Why is this player’s bat from the record-making game in the National
  Baseball Hall of Fame—but the player himself is NOT in the Baseball
  Hall of Fame?

Comment: The phrasing makes this sound like a quiz, not an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

> Who was this player?

Rennie Stennett

> For what team did he play?

Pittsburgh Pirates

> Who was the losing team?

Chicago Cubs

> Why was this game particularly embarrassing for the losing team?

They were shut out 22-0.

> What were the stats for that game?

[Box Score](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHN/CHN197509160.shtml)

> What kind of hits did he have in his seven at bats?

- Double to RF
- Single to RF (Line Drive)
- Single to CF (Line Drive)
- Double to LF (Line Drive)
- Single to RF (Ground Ball)
- Single to CF (Ground Ball)
- Triple to RF

> Who pinch-hit for this player and why?

Nobody. Willie Randolph pinch-ran for this player because reasons.

> What are the most important events in this player’s Major League Baseball career?

Randolph was a 5x All-Star selection.

> Why is this player’s bat from the record-making game in the National Baseball Hall of Fame—but the player himself is NOT in the Baseball Hall of Fame?

Without diving into much speculation, one extraordinary game does not equal an extraordinary career. To make a raw and brief comparison, [Roger Maris](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/m/marisro01.shtml) is not a Hall-Of-Famer, but had a season in which he hit the most home runs in a season, won MVP twice, and is a 7x All-Star selection. [Stennett](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/s/stennre01.shtml) finished no higher than 19th in MVP voting and was never an All-Star selection.

The most objective answer is "the voters for the baseball Hall-Of-Fame did not vote him in." In 1987, his first year of eligibility, he was [not included in the Hall-Of-Fame ballot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_Hall_of_Fame_balloting,_1987). I'm not sure if he was ever on a Hall-Of-Fame ballot, so while it is true he was never voted in, it may be true that he never had an opportunity to be voted in.